# Getting an exception when trying to add an account in Android

Tags: android, user-accounts

I'm attempting to create a means for the user to create an Account on the phone which will eventually sync to their contacts via the app. I'm working in the emulator right now, so I'm going Menu-Dev Tools-AccountsTester to test what I have. When I click on AccountsTester, I get the following error code in LogCat:

```
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.development/com.android.development.AccountsTester}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:254)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:183)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at com.android.development.AccountsTester.initializeAuthenticatorsSpinner(AccountsTester.java:147)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at com.android.development.AccountsTester.onCreate(AccountsTester.java:63)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
03-08 18:58:31.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     ... 11 more
```

As you can see there is no @ line showing where the error is occurring in my code. I google searched a few of the standout lines but couldn't find anything in relation to my problem. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here? Please let me know if there is any info you could use to help answer which I didn't include... thanks!

The layout which AccountsTester would call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        android:paddingBottom="13dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/account_login_message"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>

        <TextView 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/account_login_username_edittext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="250dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:inputType="text"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/account_login_username_fixed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/account_login_password_edittext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="250dip"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:capitalize="none"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/account_login_message_bottom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c6c3c6"
        android:minHeight="54dip"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip">

        <Button android:id="@+id/account_login_ok_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="100dip"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:onClick="handleLogin"/>

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't call a single string there... My activity references strings a few times, but the strings it references are most certainly there, I'm seeing them as I type this, and I'd get an error in Eclipse anyhow.

Comment: Could you post the layout for your activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here was that in my xml/authenticator file necessary for account creation, I filled the android:label field with "App Name" like so:

```
android:label="App Here"
```

What I needed to do was call a resource for it. So I created a string called label and put the name in there, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Actually the `icon` and `smallIcon` fields are mandatory, too.

Comment: Had the same problem, you just saved me a headache!!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably doing something like:

```
int i = 12;

((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(i);
```

You should do:

```
 int i = 12;

((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(""+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your layouts is referencing a string resource that doesn't exist.

Look for something in `res/layouts` that says `...="@string/foo"`

The other possibility is that you are calling a `setFooResource()` method with an argument of 0.

Comment: The error isn't in my my calling a getResource(...) method, it's something internal, maybe a missing method or something... I'm lookin for an answer and will provide what I find out

Comment: by the way, I've had a string of odd errors lately that I've eventually cleared up by cleaning my project (I use ant, so `ant clean`). Just a general tip.

Comment: Cleaning doesn't solve the problem. I get the feeling the issue comes from the manifest or xml files